# Cannot display comments for post

Tags: php, laravel-5

Basically, I want to show a posts comment.

Whatt is supposed to happen is that,when a user goes to view a post using a url such as `http://localhost:8000/post/show/1`,their supposed to be able to to type a comment on a post,press 'submit' ,the comment data inserted into the database,the page should reload and the comments on that post should be shown including the comment just commented by the user

BUT 
what currently happens is that after typing the comment in `http://localhost:8000/post/show/1` it inserts the comment data into the database,reloads the page but **does not show any comment** on that page.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Please help

These are my code:

**PostController.php**

```
    <?php

// PostController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'Uploader',
        ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('post');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        {


            $post =  new Post;

            $post->title = $request->get('title');
            $post->type = $request->get('type');
            $post->description = $request->get('description');
            $post->body = $request->get('body');
            $post->UniqueId = str_random(16);
            $post->Uploader = Auth::user()->name;
            $post->Language = 'en';
            $post->Location=Location::get()->countryCode;            
            $post->views = 0;
            $post->Applauds = 0;
            $post->Boos = 0;
            $post->Tags =  "hey";

                         if ($request->get('agegroup')) {
                            $post->agegroup = $request->get('agegroup');
                         } else {
                            $post->agegroup ='undefined';
                         }

            $post->AllowComments = 'true';
            $post->CommentsBg = 'default';
            $post->Visibility = 'globally public';
            $post->others = 'embeddable';


            $post->save();

            return redirect('posts');

        }
    }

   public function index()
   {
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('index', compact('posts'));
   }

   public function show($id)
   {
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('show', compact('post'));
   }
}
```

**CommentController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use App\Post;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->body = $request->get('comment_body');
        $comment->user()->associate($request->user());
        $post = Post::find($request->get('post_id'));
        $post->comments()->save($comment);

        return back();
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
Route::get('/upload', 'UploadController@index')->name('upload');

Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::post('/post/store', 'PostController@store')->name('post.store');

Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index')->name('posts');
Route::get('/post/show/{id}', 'PostController@show')->name('post.show');

Route::post('/comment/store', 'CommentController@store')->name('comment.add');
Route::post('/reply/store', 'CommentController@replyStore')->name('reply.add');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'imageupload', 'ImageController@Image');
Route::delete('delimage/{filename}', 'ImageController@Image');
```

**post.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Create Post</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('post.store') }}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @csrf
                            <label class="label">Post Title: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <label class="label">Post Type </label>
                        <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" required/>

                         <label class="label">Tags </label>
                        <input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control" required/>

                        <label class="label">Age-group(optional) </label>
                        <input type="text" name="agegroup" class="form-control" required/>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Post Description </label>
                            <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Post Body: </label>
                            <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="30" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<!-- show.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p><b>{{ $post->title }}</b></p>
                    <p>
                        {{ $post->body }}
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <h4>Display Comments</h4>
                    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
                        <div class="display-comment">
                            <strong>{{ $comment->user->name }}</strong>
                            <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    <hr />
                    <h4>Add comment</h4>
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('comment.add') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="comment_body" class="form-control" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add Comment" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $post->Id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('post.show', ['id' => $post]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Show Post</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

// Post.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
}
```

**Comment.php**

```
<?php

// Comment.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

DBSCHEMA for comments table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
// create_comments_table

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
       $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
       $table->integer('applauds')->unsigned();
       $table->integer('boos')->unsigned();
       $table->text('body');
       $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
       $table->string('commentable_type');
       $table->string('No of flags');
       $table->timestamps();
    });
}

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relationship between post and comments in your `Post` model?

Comment: Ok.I've done that

Comment: If you are sure it was saved, then it should be a problem with how you called the `Post` model before the view is rendered

Comment: If you can open tinker, see if you can load the comments on the post with `Post::find(1)->comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `PostController`function as below:

```
public function show($id)
{
  $post = Post::where('id', $id)->with('comments.user')->first();
  return view('show', compact('post'));
}
```

It should get comments and user details attached

On the `Post` Model, update `comments` function

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Can I see your DB schema for Comments Table? Or what column precisely links Post to Comment on the Comment Table?

Comment: Is `parent_id` the link to the Post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191154/discussion-between-jonathan-k-and-titox-d-boss).

Comment: THanks for trying anyways :-)